# How to add Binary framework in Swift Package Manager as dependency?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, swift-package-manager, xcode11.3

I have been searching for an answer to add framework as a dependency in Swift Package Manager, and I assume there is a way to do this but haven't succeeded in finding it.

I have tried the [solution](https://forums.swift.org/t/binary-frameworks-with-swiftpm/26225/2?u=yo2bh) provided on Swift Package Manager forum but did not succeed :(

and facing error likes `package has an unsupported layout, binary.framework/module.modulemap should be inside the 'include' directory"`

Please download the sample project for binary support from [here](https://github.com/yo2bh/SwiftPM-BinaryFrameworkSupport), which contents two frameworks add in Swift PM.

I have tried to communicate with the Swift PM community but did not get any response from them.

As there is a [proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0272-swiftpm-binary-dependencies.md) for binary framework support in the community but doesn't know when Swift PM community will be working on the same.

Is there any other way to do this? Please provide the solution for the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The proposal you mention is implemented, it will be released with Swift 5.3

Answer (score 0):

As of Swift 5.3 you can use Swift Package Manager to distribute binaries via the new `.binaryTarget()` command explained here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/distributing_binary_frameworks_as_swift_packages